# Problems passing values from one form to another

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm new to VB.net. So here is what I want to do which I am having some serious problem
Using the "Get_Computer_Name form" will post the username and account type into another form. The Get_Computer_Name also gets the computer name where it will be sent to a module and that module will work as the main connection. Now I have tried to separate the login form and form that gets the computer name but that didn't work (I also want to try that method).

The problem with my current method is that it can only perform one thing at a time. It fails to post the username and account type and it fails to send the computer name to the module. Now strangely there is a way around. If I comment out the post username and account type, the computer name will be sent to the module and the module will work and connect to the database. Now if I choose not to comment out the code that post the username and account to the other form, the computer name won't be sent to the module that handles the connection thus failing to connect to the database.

I am open to other suggestions rather than doing it this way.

Thank you

```
'Here is my code for "Get_Computer_Name form" 

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Get_Computer_Name

    Public Sub Get_Computer_Name_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        cmbcomputername.Text = My.Computer.Name
        connect()
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmbcomputername_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbcomputername.SelectedIndexChanged, cmbcomputername.TextChanged
        cmbcomputername.Text = My.Computer.Name
    End Sub

    Public Sub btnlogin_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnlogin.Click
        datasource = cmbcomputername.Text

        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            connection.Open()
        End If

        Dim reader As SqlDataReader
        Dim sqlstatement As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        sqlstatement.Connection = connection

        Try
            sqlstatement.CommandText = "Select account_username, account_password, account_type " &
            "from account_login where account_username='" & txtusername.Text & "' and account_password='" & txtpassword.Text & "'"

            reader = sqlstatement.ExecuteReader()

            If (reader.Read()) Then


                Dim application_form As application_form
                application_form = New application_form
                application_form.Show()
                application_form = Nothing
                Me.Visible = False

                'This is the code that post the username and account type to the other form (application form). If I comment this code out, the system successfully connects to the database

                application_form.lblusername.Text = (reader("account_username").ToString)
                application_form.lblaccount_type.Text = (reader("account_type").ToString)

                sqlstatement.Dispose()
                reader.Close()
                connection.Close()

            Else
                connection.Close()
                MsgBox("Invalid")
            End If
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class

'This is the code for the module that holds the main connection string

    Public connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection
    Public datasource As String
    Public database As String = "bpmi"
    Public sqlmainconnector As String

    Public Sub connect()
        sqlmainconnector = "Data Source=" & datasource & ";Initial Catalog=bpmi;Integrated Security=True"
        connection.ConnectionString = sqlmainconnector

        Try

            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                connection.Open()
            Else
                connection.Close()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try

    End Sub

'And this code is the form where the username and account type will be posted

Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class application_form

    Dim sqlcommand As SqlCommand
    Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim table As New DataTable
    Dim dategrabberapp As String
    Dim dategrabberben As String
    Dim benidgrabber As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        connect()

        filldatagrid(updateappdatagrid, updatebendatagrid)
        fillcomboboxstatus(cmbstatus)
        fillcomboboxposition(cmbappworkposition)
        fillcomboboxrelationship(cmbrelation)
        fillcomboboxrelationshipupdate(cmbrelationbenupdate)
        fillcomboboxstatusupdate(cmbappstatusupdate)
        fillcomboboxpositionupdate(cmbappworkposupdate)

'this is where the account type will got to

        If lblaccount_type.Text <> "Administrator" Then

            Me.TabControl1.TabPages(1).Enabled = False
            Me.TabControl1.TabPages(2).Enabled = False

            MsgBox("As a 'Staff', you are not permitted to do any updates")
            updateappdatagrid.Hide()
            updatebendatagrid.Hide()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: What lines are you commenting exactly?

Comment: application_form.lblusername.Text = (reader("account_username").ToString)
                application_form.lblaccount_type.Text = (reader("account_type").ToString)

Comment: if I comment out that code, it connects to the database. If I don't comment it out it doesn't connect to the database but it successfully posts the username and account type to the other form

Comment: I am confused: the username and the account type are being precisely retrieved from these two lines (if these lines are commented, both variables would be blank, isn't it?). Also I am not sure why you are saying that it connects/does not connect to the DB; is because an error is triggered?. Additionally bear in mind that you are writing reader.Close() twice; the second time, when it is already closed.

Comment: You are welcome. If there is nothing for future readers (just a small bug you realised about which cannot be written as a general help for others) and as far as this question does not have either answers nor upvotes you might want to go ahead and just delete it.