# How to obtain data from one form to another?

Tags: vb.net, forms, variables, colors

User clicks select colour in Form1, it opens Form2- they click red and click the button "Choose". Form2 closes, and the colour is set as a variable in Form1. How do I do this? Any code samples?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18445107/problems-passing-values-from-one-form-to-another?rq=1  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621610/how-to-pass-data-from-a-form-to-another-form-that-is-previously-instantiated-fro?rq=1

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand any of those two posts. I am a beginner at coding you see, this is my first project and I'm learning on the go. I hope you can understand

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You can do something called passing variables between forms.

You can do this by making a textbox/combobox a public property from the modifiers menu in design view

Look [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/332553-passing-data-between-forms/)  for information on passing variables between forms.

Also P.S - Show some of your working first, before posting just for code!

Comment: Well, I would add code if I knew where to even start. Like I said, I'm a beginner and I'm learning by looking at code and see what it does when executed ))

Comment: Start by looking at that link, that's a good start on passing variables between forms.

Comment: Maybe you should try working through a tutorial rather than just looking at bits of code that happen to do just what you want at that precise moment.